# Carrying on from django tutorial, 'get_by' list of variables

Tags: python, html, django

Basically I've done the django tutorial (just so you understand where my codes coming from) but instead of my flow going Index->Detail1->Results1->Detail2->Results2->Detail3... and so on I want it to go Index->Detail1->Detail2->Detail3...->Results.

At the moment the polls/templates/results.html says

```
<ul>
{% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% with next=object.get_next_by_pub_date %}
    {% if next %}
        <a href="{% url 'polls:detail' next.id %}" class="button next">Next</a>
    {% else %}
        <p1>There are no more questions, thank you for your time.</p1>
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

.

What I'm asking is, does anyone have a list of variables I can use in place of get_next_by_pub_date? something like get_first_by_pub_date so it gets the earliest published question? cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/):

> **Model.get_next_by_FOO(**kwargs)**
>
> **Model.get_previous_by_FOO(**kwargs)**
>
> For every DateField and DateTimeField that does not have null=True,
>   the object will have get_next_by_FOO() and get_previous_by_FOO()
>   methods, where FOO is the name of the field. This returns the next and
>   previous object with respect to the date field, raising a DoesNotExist
>   exception when appropriate.

So you can use these instance methods to get the next or previous object, ordering by some date field in the object Model.